# JSF 2 and date picker example in JSF

Tags: jsf-2

I have read many good tutorials, but still I cannot create valid JSF 2 page with date picker. I tried to create templates, following this post http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-templating-with-facelets-example/
and everything went well. But, when I tried to add RichFaces datepicker, or any other date picker, it showed nothing.

I thought it has something to do with my configuration (Tomcat 6 (and/or 7) and Eclipse), but I am not sure anymore.

The problem is that I have everything up and running, JSF, Hibernate, Spring... but when it comes to date picker, it does not recognize it, whatever I tried.

Could anyone, please, post an example with date picker?

Best,
Joksimovic

Comment: You should also not ask too broad questions, this isn't going to work. Rather concentrate on the most specific possible problem, which is in your case that RichFaces calendar didn't show anything. What exactly is the concrete problem? Couldn't you get RichFaces calendar to work? Or couldn't you get RichFaces at its whole to work? What exactly are the symptoms? "Doesn't work" doesn't really give us anything to work with. To start, look at which HTML exactly the webbrowser retrieved in place of the `<rich:calendar>`.

Comment: Thank you, BalusC. I posted this broad question because I needed anything that could work. I really lost my patience with this control... Actually, when I tried to configure my project to work with RichFaces, it keeps showing warning that it does not recognize richfaces namespace. I know that I used right namespace, I found many posts on different forums about that problem, but it still did not work. I even found that it does not work properly with Tomcat... Maybe to start with: how to configure RichFaces with Maven and Tomcat?

Comment: If the RichFaces XML namespace is not recognized, then it's just not present in the right place in the classpath (buildpath). That RichFaces doesn't work on Tomcat is nonsense. Were you using Maven to manage the build/classpath? If so, I'd concentrate on if you did that part right, this is undoubtely the root cause of your whole problem.

Comment: Well... I added reference to pom file. Besides that, I've even downloaded richfaces jar and copied it in Tomcat libs. I thought that configuring pom file is enough? I think that I added jar file to project build path, although I think that is not necessary.